# thymeleaf th:field in list in a list

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

i have a list in a list and i want to access the fields in the sublist in the html. only to print the value works fine. but i need the binding to an input field. can anyone tell me how it works? i always geht an org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property ... exception

```
public class contracts {
  public String           bez;
  public ArrayList<Years> years;
  ...getter and setter
}


public class years{
  public String                 year;    
  public ArrayList<Insurance> insurance;
  ...getter and setter
}


public class Insurance {    
   public String name;
    ...getter and setter
}

 controller:  model.addAttribute("data", initialization of all classes);   

<div  th:each="year : ${data.years}">
  <div  th:each="vs, stat : ${year.insurance}">
    <div th:text="${vs.name}"></div> -> OK!!!
    <input type="text" th:field="*{vs[__${stat.index}__].name}"></input> -> ERROR!!!
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is that the exact error message ... dot dot dot?

Comment: found the solution

change `<div  th:each="year : ${data.years}">` to `<div  th:each="year, ystat : ${data.years}">`

`<input type="text" th:field="*{years[__${ystat.index}__].insurance[__${stat.index}__].name}"></input>`